# Several devices missing from lspci-- why?

Tags: boot, pci, acer

I've installed Debian 8.3 on an Acer Aspire, model number SW5-012, with the stock kernel 4.4.0-trunk-686-pae. Mostly, it's working fine. But there are a few devices which the kernel claims not to be able to see-- particularly, the wifi and the sound:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0f)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0f)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series USB xHCI (rev 0f)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0f)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0f)
```

(I'm using a USB peripheral for networking.) The wifi and sound worked fine on the pre-installed copy of Windows. There is no hardware wifi switch. I'm not sure where to look next.

I can post my /var/log/kern.log but it's too long for the question box.

Comment: Try `lspci -vnn`. There have historically been WiFi chipsets (broadcom is an obnoxious example) which had only proprietary drivers that had to be wrenched out of Windows and jammed into Linux, but even those enumerated with lspci. Perhaps you've hit a new level of Windows lock-in games. I'd give Ubuntu 15.10 (even live-usb) a shot, as they seem to have beaten back more of the "Trusted Computing" crap.

Comment: They may be USB peripherals, try `lsusb`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run lspci -M, that will show all the devices that are missing.  I don't know why lspci does not show all devices, but lspci -M does.